purge group of old records iteratively to insert fresh data daily
We have a requirement to basically do a daily refresh of data stored in a flat table (not normalized).The flat single table itself maintains parent child relationship, that needs to regularly refreshed, by purging expired records and inserting new ones .
Below is an example data set for demonstration purposes. If we take current date as Sep 19,2024 then all below yellow+ blue highlighted rows needs purging (as program / student enrollment expired).

I was thinking of using latest Spring Batch to break problem down into below steps;

Purge all records (as a pre date set-up step) for which program itself is expired (yellow) and then no need to refresh any of it going further (until a new one is added, which job should account for in future runs).
Start the batch step with picking one school/program at a time and completely purge all data for it in table. Then do plain insert (avoiding update) of the newly fetch records (from external service), and keep repeating it for each school/program combination.

The end results for Step 1 and 2 is complete refresh of underlying table.
Finding some challenges in step 2 to fit into single record/item way, as refresh is at one level higher at school/program (rather than individual student).
Appreciate any suggestions/new alternatives etc?
Created a github demo project to demonstrate problem with using projection
https://github.com/jobas2007/batch-h2-demo.git

Why Spring Batch? Why not 1 (or 2 queries to just delete the data?). DELETE FROM table WHERE program_exp_dt < now() or enrollment_exp_dt < now(). Not sure why you want to add Spring Batch for this.

Hi, as I said, DELETE is just one part of daily maintenance. The next ask is also "add" any new records(students) that have enrolled on that particular day (and keep repeating this on daily basis), to keep prog/enrollment data up to date).

Also, I was opting for complete purge and then a fresh insert, to avoid selective "updates" if any information on existing record(student) itself changes .

i thought using projection approach (with School and Program as its properties) in Step 2 should have suffice , but it is just that unable to make it work in itemreader
